# Use regex validation in Symfony2 configuration TreeBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I'm using Symfony2's tree builder, which I see has some basic validation rules as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#validation-rules

Is there a way to also validate by regular expression?

Here's how I'm doing it at the moment, but I am not sure if this is 'best practice'. The config item I want to validate is `root_node`.

**config.yml**

```
my_bundle:
    root_node: /some/path    # this one is valid
```

**Configuration.php**

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle');

$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('root_node')
             ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();

return $treeBuilder;
```

**MyBundleExtension.php**

```
$nodePattern = '#/\w+(/w+)*#';
if (! preg_match($nodePattern, $config['root_node'])) {
    throw new \Exception("root_node is not valid: must match the pattern: $nodePattern");
}
```

So, what I'm really after is a TreeBuilder method:

```
->validate()->ifNotMatchesRegex()->thenInvalid()
```

or, failing that, the best approach to enforce my validation rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is use the `ifTrue` method with your custom function. Something like this:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('root_node')
            ->validate()
            ->ifTrue(function ($s) {
                return preg_match('#/\w+(/\w+)*#', $s) !== 1;
            })
                ->thenInvalid('Invalid path')
            ->end()
       ->end()
   ->end();
```

Note the slight modification I made to your regex.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't have hoped for a better answer. Also in the regex I missed off the ^ and $ markers, so the final version is: #^/\w+(/\w+)*$#

Comment: If you want to use custom invalid/error messages, then it might be useful to know that you can include the potentially wrong value in the message like this 'Invalid path : %s'